# Python TypeError using Scipy's coo_matrix.todense()

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, typeerror

I recently encountered difficulty when converting a `coo_matrix` to a dense matrix using `scipy`. I have a dtype `float16` sparse matrix and attempt to convert it to a dense matrix. The error complains about being given an array of type `char`. I am, however, quite certain that I am passing an array of type `float16`.

The error is:

```
    self.Xd_train = X_train.todense()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 501, in todense
  return np.asmatrix(self.toarray(order=order, out=out))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py", line 241, in toarray
  B.ravel('A'), fortran)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\sparsetools\coo.py", line 175, in coo_todense
  return _coo.coo_todense(*args)
TypeError: Array of type 'float' required.  Array of type 'char' given
```

The error appears in a class constructor:

```
self.Xd_train = X_train.todense()
```

The matrix `X_train` appears to be well-formed and definitely not of type `char`:

```
>> X_train.dtype
float16

>> X_train.shape
(6206, 4712)

>> type(X_train)
<class 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix'>

>> str(X_train)

(0, 63)       2.0
(0, 72)       1.0
(0, 76)       2.0
(0, 100)      1.0
(0, 104)      1.0
(0, 5)        1.0
(0, 10)       2.0
(0, 134)      2.0
(0, 20)       3.0
(0, 263)      1.0
(0, 264)      1.0
(0, 265)      1.0
(0, 27)       1.0
(0, 148)      2.0
(0, 32)       1.0
(0, 275)      1.0
(0, 35)       1.0
(0, 36)       1.0
(0, 279)      1.0
(0, 39)       1.0
(0, 41)       1.0
(0, 42)       1.0
(0, 52)       1.0
(0, 59)       4.0
(1, 72)       1.0
:     :
(6205, 133)   1.0
(6205, 134)   4.0
(6205, 135)   4.0
(6205, 136)   2.0
(6205, 137)   6.0
(6205, 138)   1.0
(6205, 139)   4.0
(6205, 20)    4.0
(6205, 142)   4.0
(6205, 23)    2.0
(6205, 24)    2.0
(6205, 26)    2.0
(6205, 27)    2.0
(6205, 32)    1.0
(6205, 33)    1.0
(6205, 35)    1.0
(6205, 36)    1.0
(6205, 37)    1.0
(6205, 39)    1.0
(6205, 40)    1.0
(6205, 41)    1.0
(6205, 42)    1.0
(6205, 43)    1.0
(6205, 56)    3.0
(6205, 60)    1.0
```

Any thoughts on what the problem might be? Also, let me know if additional details/information is required.

I'm using Python 2.7.2 on Windows 7, with Numpy 1.7 and Scipy 0.11. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs in the latest scipy master branch, too. E.g.

```
>>> coo_matrix([[0]], dtype=np.float16).todense()
```

raises the same exception.  The data type `np.float16` is relatively new, and there is a lot of code in scipy (and probably elsewhere) that hasn't been tested with it.

If you change your sparse matrix to `np.float32`, it should work.

I created an issue for this on the scipy github site: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2481

Comment: `float16` (and `bool`) are currently unsupported data types.